# Loading div content from external file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a `frontend.php` with the following code :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="someid" style="padding:10px; background-color:#CCCCCC">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/backend.php?id=123"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is to access `backend.php` (shown below) and retrieve some data from the database, and display it in the div on the frontend. However, **instead it displays the data on the bottom of the page.** Is there any way to specifically load the content into the div where the script is put at `frontend.php` ?

```
var link='<a href="http://example2.com/code>id=<?php echo $id?>"><img src="https://www.example.com/img/datagraph.jpg" alt="Data" width="150" height="125" border="0"></a><br/><br/>';
window.getElementById("someid").innerHTML += link;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give the `<div>` an ID:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

And then:

```
window.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += link;
```

Comment: Made the change and updated question! Unfortunately still loads at the end of the page

Comment: Not sure why, but this worked when I gave the div a different name!

Answer (score 0):

If you 'll give a chance to the [jquery library](http://jquery.com), it offers a [function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) `load()` that loads the given URI and inserts the result directly into the HTML element.

```
<div id="someId"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#someId").load("http://www.example.com/backend.php?id=123");
</script>
```